# How long is an established SSL connection valid?

Tags: ssl

Suppose I am sending "hello" to an api over ssl. My understanding is there would be a symmetric key exchange established over ssl and then the message "hello" will be encrypted using that symmetric key and sent over to the other server.

Now my question is, the next time I send a "hello 2", does the symmetric key exchange happen again? My guess would be that if it's a persistent connection, there would be no need for the key exchange again. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 1):

Meta: this doesn't appear to me to be programming, although it *might* be development and is mostly dupe [How long does SSL connection between a client and a server persist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804130/how-long-does-ssl-connection-between-a-client-and-a-server-persist) .

It depends on the application protocol used on top of SSL (which since 1999 is really TLS, although many things e.g. implementation classes still use the old name) and usually the implementations at both ends. For example, HTTP/1.1 defaults to connection persistence (which was often done in 1.0 as an extension called keep-alive), but either endpoint can change this by specifying `connection: close`, and even if the connection is kept open can choose to close it anytime later, perhaps after a minute or two, perhaps after a day or a week. The HTTPS implementation in browsers usually keeps connections open for a little while but has limits on the total connections open so those that haven't been used recently may need to be closed when others are opened. Other applications, libraries, and platforms vary. Other protocols also vary; for example an email agent using SMTPS would normally make a connection, transmit one or more emails, and then disconnect.

In addition, SSL-now-TLS through 1.2 supports  **session resumption**, which allows the keyexchange (and other handshake results) performed on one connection to be saved (at both endpoints, or with the 'ticket' option, at client only) and reused on a new connection, for as long as the endpoint(s) agree; implementations usually call this session caching. See e.g. [RFC 5246 section 7.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-7.3) specifically the part starting in the middle of page 36, and for one fairly common server (Apache) see [SessionCache and SessionCacheTimeout directives](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4//mod/mod_ssl.html#sslsessioncache). Resumption uses a new *handshake* but not a full keyexchange on that handshake.

However, this creates a security vulnerability if an endpoint's sesssion cache is compromised, so TLS 1.3 replaces it with a different method using dynamically created PSKs; see [RFC 8446 section 2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-2.2). This allows either a partial handshake (doing the actual keyexchange with [EC]DHE but authentication tied to the previous session by the PSK rather than full certificate-based authentication) which provides [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy), or a minimal handshake (using the PSK both as the new initial secret and for authentication) which does not.

If you want an answer for specific software, and specific server(s), you need to look at the capabilities and configuration, and often also the current status, of that software and those server(s).